# ShareStatusTask doubles Status on WP8.1 Facebook share

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

I have a simple C# WP8.0 application from where I launch, on a button click, the ShareStatusTask.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = new ShareStatusTask { Status = "Test message", };
    task.Show();
}
```

When I choose to share on Facebook, Messaging, OneNote etc everything works fine on a WP8 device.

The same application running on a WP8.1 device doubles the Status text only on Facebook share.

I would like to have same behavior as on WP8. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ShareLinkTask instead of ShareStatusTask. Lucky me I needed anyway to add a link to the message.